An upper bound of order of prime divisors
Let $X$ be a normal projective variety, $Z\subseteq X$ a closed subvariety, and suppose that $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ is an ideal sheaf. I tried to prove the following:

There is a positive number $C>0$ such that
$$ \mathrm{ord}_E\mathfrak{a}\le C\mathrm{ord}_EZ$$
holds for any prime divisor $E$ over $X$ whose center on $X$ is in $Z$. ($C$ does not depend on $E$.)

Can we prove this one? If $Z$ contains both the singular locus and the locus of $\mathfrak{a}$, then it is Proposition 2.4 in [BdFFU15]. (But I don't follow the proof) Can we drop the condition?
[BdFFU15]:  S. Boucksom, T. de Fernex, C. Favre, and S. Urbinati: Valuation spaces and multiplier ideals on singular varieties, Recent advances in algebraic geometry, London Math. Soc.
Lecture Note Ser. 417 (2015), 29–51, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge.

maybe you need to show that $I_Z^C\subset a$ for sufficiently large $C$?

No. In general, $\mathcal{I}^C_Z\subseteq\mathfrak{a}$ is false. (Just take $X=\mathbb{P}^2, Z={\mathrm{pt}},$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal sheaf of an ample divisor on $X$ passing $Z$.)

in your example Z does not contain the locus of a

Sorry for inconvenience, there is no assumption that $Z$ contains the locus of $\mathfrak{a}$... Maybe I added the assumption because I obessed in the condition in [BdFFU15].
